# Wagtail basic menu separators for all but last item in template

Tags: templates, menuitem, wagtail, separator

I am creating a basic bootstrap navbar menu in Wagtail based on steps 1 to 3 of [this guide](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/wagtail-tutorial-12-how-create-and-manage-menus-wagtail-application/). My menu items need to have a separator in between each item like this :

> Item One **/**   Item Two   **/**   Item Three

However if I add a separator in I end up with one after the last item in the menu :

```
{% for menu in menuitems %}
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.title}}</a> /
{% endfor %}
```

Results in this ...

> Item One   **/**   Item Two   **/**   Item Three   **/**

How do I separate the items without adding a trailing divider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.title}}</a> /
```

to this:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.title}}</a>{% if not forloop.last %} /{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what the answer should be.